# toHaveBeenCalled() failing when mocked output shows correct data

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I am getting tired of trying to figure out the following out. Basically I have a method in my component that calls a service which is mocked. Once that service completes, another service does some logging activities, which is also mocked. But my test fails saying the logging service wasn't called:

```
       process(){
       const that : any = this;
      this.mainService.process().then(result=>{

       return result;

    }).then(result=>{
      //log the operation now after doing some checkups
      let checkups = ""
      that.logService.log('process',result, checkups).then(logged=>{
        console.log(logged)

      }).catch(err=>console.log(err)
    }).catch(err=>console.log(err);

    }
```

Before we go ahead, doing Promise.all() isn't match of an option due to the logic in place to do checkups. Now to the testing bit:

```
fit("should log processed request", done => {
  const mainSerivce = TestBed.get(MainService)
  const logService = TestBed.get(LogService)
  spyOn(mainService, "process").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({id:34,value:64, rank:310));
  const logSpy = spyOn(logSerivce, "log").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({'done':true}))


  fixture.whenStable().then(finished=>{

    component.process();

    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();

  })

});


expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

fails now but I can see in my console the result of the mock {'done':true} or whatever value I pass is shown, meaning it was mocked and called (?). What am I missing exactly since the methods appear to have been mocked and logged correctly in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you have to wait for the promises to resolve before asserting for it, try:

```
fit("should log processed request", done => {
  const mainSerivce = TestBed.get(MainService)
  const logService = TestBed.get(LogService)
  spyOn(mainService, "process").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({id:34,value:64, rank:310));
  const logSpy = spyOn(logSerivce, "log").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({'done':true}));
  // call the function that will resolve promises
  component.process();
  // whenStable waits for the promises to resolve.
  fixture.whenStable().then(finished=>{
    console.log('Making the assertion !!');
    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
});
```

Make sure you see the log of `{ 'done': true }` before the log of `Making the assertion !!`. But since you have a promise resolving within a promise, the following might fix it.

```
fit("should log processed request", async done => { // check out the async keyword here
  const mainSerivce = TestBed.get(MainService)
  const logService = TestBed.get(LogService)
  spyOn(mainService, "process").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({id:34,value:64, rank:310));
  const logSpy = spyOn(logSerivce, "log").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({'done':true}));
  // call the function that will resolve promises
  component.process();
  // when stable waits for the promises to resolve.
  await fixture.whenStable();
  await fixture.whenStable();
  expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  done();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AliF50! In fact, i wasn't waiting for one of the promises to finish!